# Graphviz node labels not respected when using ranks

Tags: graphviz

I am having a little trouble with Graphviz and node labels.

When I do this;

```
A[label="Foo Baz"];
B[label="Bar Baz"];
A -> B;
```

I get a graph that correctly labels the nodes "Foo Baz" and "Bar Baz" respectively.

However, when I do this;

```
A[label="Foo Baz"];
B[label="Bar Baz"];
A -> B;
{ rank=same; A B};
```

I get a graph that incorrectly labels the nodes "A" and "B" respectively.

In other words, by using a rank specifier, Graphviz appears to stop respecting the label attributes that I have put on the nodes.

I tried using "Foo Baz" and "Bar Baz" in the rank specifier like this;

```
A[label="Foo Baz"];
B[label="Bar Baz"];
A -> B;
{ rank=same; 'Foo Baz' 'Foo Bar'};
```

But that just causes an error (probably correctly, I would think).

So I am a bit stumped. Would anyone be able to guide me as to where I am going wrong with this? Does order of declaration matter, perhaps?

Regards,
Ben

**edit**

Further to this, I can provide another example;

This works (displays the correct label);

```
A[shape=doublecircle, label=\"Foo Baz\", style=filled; fontname=Helvetica; fontsize=8];
```

This does not (ignores the label attribute);

```
{ rank=max; A[shape=doublecircle, label=\"Foo Baz\", style=filled; fontname=Helvetica; fontsize=8]; }
```

So the exact same node declaration except for the rank specifier.

Comment: No such problems here. Your second code exaple produces the expected result on my machine (Debian Etch, graphviz version 2.38.0).

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I am on OSX (El Capitan) and have confirmed that Graphviz version 2.38.0 is installed. Perhaps I will try this on my Heroku server and report back... thanks again.